# How does the NAND Gate work using Transistors

Tags: transistors, digital-logic

I recently learned about the NAND gate circuit with transistors in my circuits class as shown below.

[image: d]

Unfortunately I'm having a very difficult time comprehending as to why the output is 1 when A or B is turned on. It seems to me that if a voltage source is connected to A or B and is turned with sufficient voltage to produce a current V_{out} will not be V_{cc}.

Comment: There's a phase reversal.  i.e. there's zero voltage across a short, which the turned on transistors essentially become. also: common emitter= phase reversal.

Comment: Why is there zero voltage across a turned on transistor?

Comment: There's a slight voltage drop.  okay, you got me.  I did say essentially.

Comment: The definition of a turned-on transistor is that the collector emitter conducts current easily. That is, for a small voltage you get a big current. So, for a small to medium current you get an even smaller voltage. Just as with a mechanical switch- when it is turned on there is little voltage across it, which allows most of the voltage to appear across the load.

Comment: @"Tim Spriggs" Sorry I wasn't trying to nit pick at all I just genuinely don't understand lol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be a little easier to understand if we start with switches:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWpgJa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Hard-wired NAND gate.*

Here it should be obvious that Q will be pulled high unless *both* SW1 and SW2 are closed. When both are closed Q will be pulled low (to ground).

- The transistors in your example behave as switches controlled by current injected into their bases. If no current is injected into the base then no current will flow from collector to emitter and they behave as open switches.
- If enough current is injected into the base (by connecting it to a positive supply, usually through a current limiting resistor) then current *can* flow from the collector to the emitter.
- I have italicised "can" because it can only flow if there is somewhere for it to go. This would be similar to closing SW1 of Figure 1 but leaving SW2 open. Current *can* flow through SW1 but can't because SW2 is open and the current has nowhere to go.

I hope that makes some sense.

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot more sense now, I was under the impression before that if one of the transistors was "on" then the current from that transistor would also flow through the other transistor turning it "on" despite the voltage source corresponding to that transistor being turned off.

Comment: I didn't want to bog you down in details but there has to be a path from the emitter to ground before any base current will flow. So if A is high but B is low then T2 will be off (open circuit) and no base current will flow through T1 as there is no path to ground.

Comment: Interesting, I will definitely keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

When A=0,B=1 or A=1,B=0 or A=0,B=0 i.e. when one (or both) of the transistors is off, there is no current through the transistors or the resistor, as there is no current in the resistor its voltage drop is zero, this means that both ends of the resistor are at the same voltage, that is Vcc.

Comment: I suppose what I don't understand is why is there no current through the transistors or resistor when A or B is 1 since shouldn't the transistor in the "on" state have a current flowing through it now? Does it have something to do with the reverse bias on the transistor?

Comment: I typically shy away from the water analogy, but it works here. If you have two water valves in a pipe and you close the upstream one and open the downstream one, will water flow through the valves? No, the open valve will just be a dry opening.

Answer (score 0):

For current to flow from the base and collector to the emitter of an NPN BJT, the emitter has to be at a lower potential than the base and the base at lower potential than the collector.

When the T1 is turned ON (by applying some voltage > 0.7 V to its base) and T2 is OFF, T1's emitter is floating since it is connected to T2's collector, which is floating since T2 is OFF or OPEN. So the condition mentioned above isnt satisfied and no current flows from collector to emitter. The same goes for when T1 is OFF and T2 is ON; T2's collector is floating because of the high-Z T1 emitter.

Only when both transistors are ON, do all the terminals assume *definite* states (as opposed to floating) and thus current flows from VCC through T1 collector, through T2 emitter to GND. You'll notice the condition I mentioned above is satisfied in this case.